# Find document by date - MongoDB - Python

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have documents in a MongoDB collection that have a filed 'date'. In the Mongo Shell they appear as ISO Date.

For example:

```
"date" : ISODate("2015-12-21T09:00:05.396Z")
```

I would like to find documents within a certain range date.

The documents were inserted with PyMongo if it makes any difference.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operate regular Python `datetime` objects ([documentation sample](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#range-queries)):

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2015, 12, 20, 7, 51, 04)
end = datetime(2015, 12, 21, 7, 52, 04)

col.find_one({'date': {'$lt': end, '$gt': start}})
```